# grails "unable to find valid certification path to requested target"

Tags: grails

I am using grails 2.2.1. I am new in grails. I am trying to implement the mail plugin in my grails but some error is coming which i am not able to solve.

The exception is:

```
Class: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException
Message: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

My mail plugin send method:

```
def send = {
    sendMail {
        to params.email    
        subject params.subject   
        body params.body
    }

    render "Mail Sent"
}
```

Comment: I am also facing the same problem. Did you solve this ??

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you are connecting to your mail server via SSL and you do not have the servers certificate in your trust store.

I think your options are

- to not use SSL
- to get hold of the servers cert and trust it ( by either installing it in your JVM trust store, or in a trust store local to your application )
- to choose to trust all hosts for your javamail installation by setting the `mail.imaps.ssl.trust` property ( assuming you are using imap )

Of these three, the third should not be done in a production environment as it's effectively the same as not using SSL.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Please check my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17547949/grails-send-mail-is-not-working)

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you are using windows XP. If yes then you should install windows 7 or not then setup your OS again with windows 7 or later. Cause I was in the same problem. But now it's solved. I have tried other plugin for mail but no result except this. You should try it.